# Priority Queue behavior when Priority is same

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I was trying out the PriorityQueue in .Net 6 and was puzzled by the following behavior. I was wondering if anyone could help me understand it better.

Consider the following code.

```
var priortyQueue = new PriorityQueue<string,int>();
priortyQueue.Enqueue("A",1);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("C-1",3);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("C-2",3);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("D", 4);

while (priortyQueue.TryDequeue(out var str,out var priority))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Element:{str} with Priority {priority}");
}
```

This would produce an output as the following.

```
Element:A with Priority 1
Element:C-1 with Priority 3
Element:C-2 with Priority 3
Element:D with Priority 4
```

This looks fine, but please keep an eye on the position or order in which "C-1" and "C-2" are dequeued.

Now if I was to change the above code and add another enqueue statement between insertion of "C1" and "C2", things changes slightly.

```
var priortyQueue = new PriorityQueue<string,int>();
priortyQueue.Enqueue("A",1);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("C-1",3);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("B", 2); // change here
priortyQueue.Enqueue("C-2",3);
priortyQueue.Enqueue("D", 4);
```

The output of the above would be

```
Element:A with Priority 1
Element:B with Priority 2
Element:C-2 with Priority 3  // Order is reversed
Element:C-1 with Priority 3
Element:D with Priority 4
```

As you can observe the position of "C2" and "C1" has changed now. I was curious why the FIFO is not followed when the Priority is the same. Please note this behavior is applicable only when

- "B" has priority less than "C1" and "C2"
- "B" is enqueued after "C1" and before "C2".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was never a guarantee of what order the elements of equal priority will get.

However, from the source code the mechanics of the list isn't just an ordered array, and uses some sort of linked style list from the last node, moving each node one step back until it finds a comparison using whatever comparer you gave it (or default), until it can find a place it can go.

In this case, the order of insertions counts and can produce exactly the artifacts you see.

Why you may ask, likely because it's more efficient, however one would need to track down the design minutes, discussion and paper trial as to why they chose this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a misunderstanding to Heap/Priority Queue.

It is not guaranteed to be in order. Only the top one is guaranteed to be the minimum or maxmum.